# Qt won't run example application after I installed Visual Studio 2019 and Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, visual-studio-2019

Qt (Qt Creator 4.10.1 and Qt 5.13.1) stopped running applications found in its examples catalog after I installed Visual Studio 2019. Before I installed Visual Studio 2019, Qt was working fine. Now it tells me `E:/Qt/5.12.5/mingw73_32/mkspecs/features/toolchain.prf(76): Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined.` and it stops, with only the `.pro` file included in the project.

Around the same time that I installed Visual Studio I also installed the Unreal Engine.

Comment: why does it refers to 5.12.5 while you are saying that 5.13.1 is in use? try to remove older Qt kits from Qt Creator if you no longer use those old versions.

Comment: It appears that that's the only mingw installed. I just reinstalled Qt, it's odd the versions don't match.

Comment: Recently, I saw something similar on my side: I ran CMake to recreate build dir. of my professional work. Afterwards, I got compiler errors. Digging deeper, I found that CMake had picked up the wrong Qt version. The required was part of the project dir. but I had installed a new Qt version for toying and this was the one CMake picked. (Env. variables? Registry entries? I don't know.) The fix: I checked the variables in the CMake GUI and fixed the dir settings for Qt to my needs. Afterwards it was running fine again.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by removing "C:\Qt\5.15.0\msvc2019_64\bin" from the ComSpec environment variable under build settings. No clue why it showed up there, but it happened after I built a library using cmake and visual studio.

The only thing that should be in ComSpec is the path to cmd.exe as far as I know. I spent hours looking for a solution only to find dead ends. I finally figured this out after cross referencing my qt project on a second machine.